# still didnt get @android:id/list vs @+id/listView1

Tags: android

when extending listactivity it is must to have a @android:id/list

question 1> what if i want to implement 2 listviews then ids will be same @android:id/list.

question 2> in what scenario i should use @+id/listView1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the relationship between the data in the 2 listviews you intend to display?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the ID is independant(unless you don't name them uniquely) so you'd use the "@+id/listView1" solution every time as far as I know. I did this on my own Android app and it worked just fine.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: Well, if you're using a ListActivity this is true, as the Android framework would be looking for a list with the id of 'list'. But as far as I'm aware you cannot have more than one list on a ListActivity? You'd have to end up writing your own ListAdapter to manage multiple ListViews on an Activity. After that you can define seperate xml files for layouts and such.

Answer (score 1):

`ListActivity` is basically a 'convenience' class which simply extends `Activity` and has a single `ListView` plus some convenience methods for handling it - there's nothing particularly special about it.

If you want an `Activity` which has more than one `ListView` then it would be better to simply create your own from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Xml with let's say a relativelayout that contains a imageview on the top and a listview in the middle and a button in the bottom. Then you need to set an uniqe ID for your listview to gain access to it. 
ex:

```
<ListView
   android:"@+id/unique_listview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="400px"
/>
```

Then you can customize and populate the listView with this:

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.unique_listview);
myList.setAdapter(new myListAdapter(this));


private class myListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
....
}
```